# Flutter web - the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found), main.dart.js:1

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Flutter web project works smoothly when running directly into chrome from IDE, but after calling `flutter build web`, and hosting the built web app is not opening(only a blank page) and showing this error which is

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.dart.js:1 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8080/') with script ('http://localhost:8080/flutter_service_worker.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

[image]

Comment: Did you say you hosted the app? Like on a web server not locally?

Comment: yes I hosted it locally

Comment: Okay then i was guessing the issue was due to using "localhost" in the URL but if its still locally hosted then that's not the issue.

Comment: I am also having this issue, for website hosted on netlify.
Any Solutions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you publish resources not `/build/web` but `/web`?

Comment: actually hosting the one inside `/build/web` works but not the one inside `/web` ? why is that ?

Comment: `/web` files is not real resources, It's just configure for build

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't publish `/build/web` just publish `/web` folder's resources.
If you are hosting it with github then goto ***index.html*** and then change

`<base href="/">`
**to**
`<base href="/YourRepoName/">`

This worked for me..

Answer (score 2):

I'm using nginx locally on my laptop to "force" flutter to serve my page.
The simplest config that I needed:

```
server {
    listen       8004;
    server_name  your-domain.local;

    location / {
        root   /path/to/your/project/build/web;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

That's enough, the page is working without any problems :)

Answer (score 1):

In case if you are setting up backend with frontend you might need to look for the single page web app configuration.
For me i was using  `| golang + echo(framework) + flutter |` so for me the routes does't know my application is SPA(single page application) for that I need to

```
e := echo.New()
e.Use(middleware.StaticWithConfig(middleware.StaticConfig{
    HTML5:      true,
    Root:       "web", // because files are located in `web` directory in `webAssets` fs
    Filesystem: http.FS(webAssets),
}))
```